# How to scope field components based on record properties

Tags: react-admin

In react-admin, how do I access the record properties to show only certain components based on a record property value?

In the following code I want to only show the Bearer Token if the record name is not "All"; if the record name is "All", then only show if the user's role is "admin".

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in the OrgShow component, shown below, which I believe is saying that there is no "props". I've also tried "record" and "name", none of which are available.

```
export const OrgShow = ({ permissions, ...props }) => (
  <Show permissions={permissions} title={<Title />} {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout permissions={permissions}>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      {
        (props.record.name === 'All' && permissions === 'admin') || (props.record.name !== 'All' && permissions === 'user')
          ? <TextField source="bearer_token" />
          : [
            <FunctionField label='Bearer Token' render={record => obfuscator(record.bearer_token)} />,
            <Alert severity="warning">You are not authorized for this org.</Alert>
          ]
      }
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

UPDATE:
I ended up solving this by using a FunctionField component, which I think is similar to user striped's solution; main difference being that FunctionField seems to be great for one-off function, whereas creating a new component seems appropriate if you're going to use that logic for more than one source.  Anyway, here's the solution I came up with:

```
export const OrgShow = ({ permissions, ...props }) => (
  <Show permissions={permissions} title={<Title />} {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout permissions={permissions}>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <FunctionField permissions={permissions} label='Bearer Token' render={record => {
        if ((record.name === 'All' && permissions === 'admin') || record.name !== 'All') {
          return record.bearer_token
        } else {
          return obfuscator(record.bearer_token)
        }
      }} />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

Comment: You can also use the <FormDataConsumer> component:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create a specific component. The record should be automatically propagated to the child:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (props.record.name === 'All' && props.permissions === 'admin') || (props.record.name !== 'All' && props.permissions === 'user')
    ? <TextField source="bearer_token" record={props.record}/>
    : [
      <FunctionField label='Bearer Token' record={props.record} render={record => obfuscator(record.bearer_token)} />,
      <Alert severity="warning">You are not authorized for this org.</Alert>
    ]
}

export const OrgShow = ({ permissions, ...props }) => (
  <Show permissions={permissions} title={<Title />} {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout permissions={permissions}>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <MyComponent permission={permissions} />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```